# Required field validator is not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery, mvc

Here is my code Index.cshtml
I gave JavaScript functions but validations is not working please check this where i did mistake in this code.

Product List

```
        <table class="table table-striped">

                <tr>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>

                    <th>ProductName</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>ProductId</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>

                </tr>

            <tbody>
                @foreach (SharePointAppSampleWeb.Models.Product objProduct in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>@objProduct.ProductName</td>
                        <td>@objProduct.Category</td>
                        <td>@objProduct.Price</td>
                        <td>@objProduct.ProductId</td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = objProduct.ProductId }) | @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = objProduct.ProductId })| @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = objProduct.ProductId })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Add Product</a>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">New Product</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal well" name="form1" id="form1">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="productTitle">ProductName</label>
                                    <input name="productTitle" class="form-control" id="productTitle" type="text" placeholder="Enter product title">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="productDescription">Category</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="productDescription" class="form-control" id="productDescription" placeholder="Enter product description">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="productPrice">Price</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productPrice" placeholder="Enter product price">
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">                            
                        <button id="btnClose" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button id="btnSaveProduct" type="button"  class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

                    </div>

                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
      </div>
  </div>
```

```
  @section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">

    debugger




    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#form1").validate({
                    rules: {
                        productTitle: "required"
                    },
                    messages: {
                        productTitle: "Please specify your name"

                    }
        })


    $("#btnSaveProduct").click(function (e) {

        //e.preventDefault();
        $("#form1").valid();
        var spHostUrl = getSPHostUrlFromQueryString(window.location.search);

        var urlAddProduct = "/Home/AddProduct?SPHostUrl=" + spHostUrl;

        $.post(urlAddProduct,
                {
                    title: $("#productTitle").val(),
                    description: $("#productDescription").val(),
                    price: $("#productPrice").val(),

                }).done(function () {
                    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                    location.reload()

                })


                .fail(function () {
                    alert("Failed to add the new product!");
                });
    });

    // Gets SPHostUrl from the given query string.
    function getSPHostUrlFromQueryString(queryString) {
        if (queryString) {
            if (queryString[0] === "?") {
                queryString = queryString.substring(1);
            }

            var keyValuePairArray = queryString.split("&");

            for (var i = 0; i < keyValuePairArray.length; i++) {
                var currentKeyValuePair = keyValuePairArray[i].split("=");

                if (currentKeyValuePair.length > 1 && currentKeyValuePair[0] == "SPHostUrl") {
                    return currentKeyValuePair[1];
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why you are calling this below function two time?**

```
$("#form1").validate({
                    rules: {
                        productTitle: "required"
                    },
                    messages: {
                        productTitle: "Please specify your name"

                    }
        })
```

Comment: Sorry for that,I did't see that now i edited.I called one time only but required field is not validating.